# Support of étale sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme, $i: Z\to X$ a closed subscheme, $j: U\to X$ its complement in $X$. Assume the codimension of $Z$ in $X$ is large (at least $2$).

Let $A$ be an étale sheaf on $U$, $B$ an étale sheaf on $Z$, and consider the étale sheaf on $X$:

$$C:= j_{ *}(A)\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}i_{*}(B).$$

Is $C$ zero? This doesn't seem obvious to me, but perhaps I'm missing the obvious.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $U\to X$ is a dense open with $X$ irreducible and regular and $A$ is a constant sheaf, for instance $A=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$, then $j_*(A)=A$, so in this case $C$ will usually not be zero

Comment: What if $Z$ has codimension $\ge 2$?

Comment: Still the example applies, so $C$ can be nonzero